# How to scale up a boat design?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, dimensional-analysis

I've been trying to research how to scale up a boat design.
Specifically I am trying to find out how much power will be needed to "drive" the boat?

Suppose I know that a 250 mm model boat, with 100 W power supply, goes 2 m/s. If I want a 25 m boat, how do I scale up the power requirements to maintain 2 m/s?

I'm not looking for the answer, I am looking for the areas to research, ideally some papers to study.

Comment: I seem to recall a rule of thumb that running scale models in water is not a good approximation for scales of much more than 3:1, because the ratio of viscous to dynamic effects gets too far out of whack. So there may be no good answer for a 100:1 model unless you test it in some low viscosity fluid.

Comment: You have added a few more terms for me to go google!! Which will help!  Thank you!

Comment: You could try looking for something called 'dynamic similarity' aka 'dynamic similitude' .

Comment: The standard way of doing scale up is to work in terms of dimensionless groups.  Do you know how to do dimensional analysis using the Buckingham Pi theorem?  This is what @Quantumspaghettification is referring to.

Comment: I believe that the friction force of the water is not linear, therefore the amount of power required will be grater than 10 kW.  If the friction force goes up as the square of the surface area, you might need (100 x 100 =)10,000 times the power, = 1,000 kW!  So, the point is that you need to find out how the friction force varies with the surface area and its shape.